# How to use ActiveSupport::Configurable with Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration, rails-engines

I want to give my [rails engine gem](https://github.com/antpaw/bhf/blob/master/lib/bhf.rb) a proper configuration possibilities.
Something that looks like this in `initializers/my_gem.rb` [(link to the current initializer)](https://github.com/antpaw/bhf-demo/blob/master/config/initializers/bhf.rb):

```
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.awesome_var = true
  # config.param_name = :page
end
```

So I've looked around for any clues in other gems and the best I cloud find was this [`kaminari/config.rb`](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/lib/kaminari/config.rb).
But it looks so hacky that I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 15):

The source file for `ActiveSupport::Configurable` got decent documentation:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/configurable.rb

I like to put the configuration into it's own class within the engine (like kaminari does):

```
class MyGem
  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end

  def self.configure
    yield configuration
  end
end

class MyGem::Configuration
  include ActiveSupport::Configurable

  config_accessor(:foo) { "use a block to set default value" }
  config_accessor(:bar) # no default (nil)
end
```

Now I can configure the engine with this API:

```
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.bar = 'baz'
end
```

And access the configuration with

```
MyGem.configuration.bar
```

Comment: Thanks, https://github.com/antpaw/bhf/blob/master/lib/bhf.rb i couldn't figure out the yield part

Answer (score -3):

try this out

I hope this is simple and clear.

[Example Code](https://github.com/sachin87/honcho/blob/master/lib/honcho/engine.rb)

Comment: But it doesn't use ActiveSupport::Configurable and it's very redudant