# access configuration in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to build a gem for my company that will log stats that can be dropped into any of the rails apps throughout the company. As part of this gem I need to start a statsd client and assign it to a global variable. So right now it looks something like this:

```
$stats =  Statsd.new('127.0.0.1', 8125).tap{|sd| sd.namespace = 'some_hard_coded_namespace'}
```

Currently I have this at the bottom of my main gem file so it gets called on start up and is available for the rails app to use to start logging data. My problem is that I would like this to be able to be specified in a configuration instead of being hard-coded into the gem. My first thought was to do something like this:

```
def get_namespace
  return Rails.application.config.stats_logging_namespace
rescue Exception => e
  return Rails.application.class.to_s.split("::").first.underscore.dasherize
end
```

But since the gem is loaded before `config/application.rb` I can't actually access those variables. Is there a proper way to allow a user to configure variables for a gem? For instance maybe in a yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to configure a gem is to have an initializer in the application where the gem is used.

config/initializers/my_gem.rb:

```
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.namespace = 'the_namespace'
end
```

See this answer for an example on how you can implement the configuration API in the gem:
[How to use ActiveSupport::Configurable with Rails Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104246/how-to-use-activesupportconfigurable-with-rails-engine/24151439#24151439)

Comment: This looks good, my only concern is I don't think this gets executed until after the gem is loaded. Or does this get loaded before the gem?

Comment: You're right, the gem is loaded first so with that approach you'll need a mechanism in the gem that puts the stat tracking on hold until the configuration is done.