# Using variables in a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, initializer

What is the correct way to use configurable variables in a Ruby gem to be used in a Rails app?  We use timezone in this example which is likely a constant but would also be using installation-specific variables such as `home_city`, etc.

1. Constants
   Can set constants in an initializer:

   ```
   config/initializer/mygem.rb
   TIMEZONE = "Eastern Standard"
   ```

   However, if used in an class variable declaration, the variable is not defined.

   ```
   module Foo
     module Bar
       class TickTock  
         class_attribute :tz  
         self.tz = "#{TIMEZONE} Time zone"  # uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::TickTock::TIMEZONE
   ```
2. Config variables

   ```
   config/initializer/mygem.rb  
   config.x.timezone = "Eastern Standard"
   ```

   ```
   module Foo
     module Bar
       class TickTock  
         self.tz = "#{Rails.configuration.x.timezone} Time zone" # undefined method `configuration` for Foo::Bar::TickTock:Module
   ```
3. Environment variables:  We would prefer not use environment variables in the gem itself.  We would like to avoid

   ```
   self.tz = "#{ENV['TIMEZONE']} Time zone"
   ```
4. Other

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is use `ActiveSupport::Configurable` [module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Configurable.html).

With this module, you can create a configuration file like this:

**/config/initializers/my_gem.rb**

```
MyGem.config do |config|
  config.timezone = 'BRT'
end
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24151439/740394) can be usefull too.